# Fabricjs snap to grid on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I'm having some issues trying to get the objects to resize according to the grid size.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/csh6c6fw/1/

this is the code that I'm applying:

```
canvas.on('object:scaling', (options) => {
  var newWidth = (Math.round(options.target.getWidth() / grid)) * grid;
  var newHeight = (Math.round(options.target.getHeight() / grid)) * grid;

  if (options.target.getWidth() !== newWidth) {
    options.target.set({ width: newWidth, height: newHeight });
  }

});
```

**Expected Result**

It's supposed to snap to the grids like the movement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Might seem pretty complicated but, the following will get the job done :

```
canvas.on('object:scaling', options => {
   var target = options.target,
      w = target.width * target.scaleX,
      h = target.height * target.scaleY,
      snap = { // Closest snapping points
         top: Math.round(target.top / grid) * grid,
         left: Math.round(target.left / grid) * grid,
         bottom: Math.round((target.top + h) / grid) * grid,
         right: Math.round((target.left + w) / grid) * grid
      },
      threshold = grid,
      dist = { // Distance from snapping points
         top: Math.abs(snap.top - target.top),
         left: Math.abs(snap.left - target.left),
         bottom: Math.abs(snap.bottom - target.top - h),
         right: Math.abs(snap.right - target.left - w)
      },
      attrs = {
         scaleX: target.scaleX,
         scaleY: target.scaleY,
         top: target.top,
         left: target.left
      };
   switch (target.__corner) {
      case 'tl':
         if (dist.left < dist.top && dist.left < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (w - (snap.left - target.left)) / target.width;
            attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
            attrs.top = target.top + (h - target.height * attrs.scaleY);
            attrs.left = snap.left;
         } else if (dist.top < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (h - (snap.top - target.top)) / target.height;
            attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
            attrs.left = attrs.left + (w - target.width * attrs.scaleX);
            attrs.top = snap.top;
         }
         break;
      case 'mt':
         if (dist.top < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (h - (snap.top - target.top)) / target.height;
            attrs.top = snap.top;
         }
         break;
      case 'tr':
         if (dist.right < dist.top && dist.right < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (snap.right - target.left) / target.width;
            attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
            attrs.top = target.top + (h - target.height * attrs.scaleY);
         } else if (dist.top < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (h - (snap.top - target.top)) / target.height;
            attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
            attrs.top = snap.top;
         }
         break;
      case 'ml':
         if (dist.left < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (w - (snap.left - target.left)) / target.width;
            attrs.left = snap.left;
         }
         break;
      case 'mr':
         if (dist.right < threshold) attrs.scaleX = (snap.right - target.left) / target.width;
         break;
      case 'bl':
         if (dist.left < dist.bottom && dist.left < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (w - (snap.left - target.left)) / target.width;
            attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
            attrs.left = snap.left;
         } else if (dist.bottom < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (snap.bottom - target.top) / target.height;
            attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
            attrs.left = attrs.left + (w - target.width * attrs.scaleX);
         }
         break;
      case 'mb':
         if (dist.bottom < threshold) attrs.scaleY = (snap.bottom - target.top) / target.height;
         break;
      case 'br':
         if (dist.right < dist.bottom && dist.right < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (snap.right - target.left) / target.width;
            attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
         } else if (dist.bottom < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (snap.bottom - target.top) / target.height;
            attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
         }
         break;
   }
   target.set(attrs);
});
```

Here is a working example :

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
   selection: false
});
var grid = 50;

// create grid
for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
   canvas.add(new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], {
      stroke: '#ccc',
      selectable: false
   }));
   canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], {
      stroke: '#ccc',
      selectable: false
   }))
}

// add objects
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
   left: 100,
   top: 100,
   width: 50,
   height: 50,
   fill: '#faa',
   originX: 'left',
   originY: 'top',
   centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
   left: 300,
   top: 300,
   radius: 50,
   fill: '#9f9',
   originX: 'left',
   originY: 'top',
   centeredRotation: true
}));

// snap to grid
canvas.on('object:moving', options => {
   options.target.set({
      left: Math.round(options.target.left / grid) * grid,
      top: Math.round(options.target.top / grid) * grid
   });
});

canvas.on('object:scaling', options => {
   var target = options.target,
      w = target.width * target.scaleX,
      h = target.height * target.scaleY,
      snap = { // Closest snapping points
         top: Math.round(target.top / grid) * grid,
         left: Math.round(target.left / grid) * grid,
         bottom: Math.round((target.top + h) / grid) * grid,
         right: Math.round((target.left + w) / grid) * grid
      },
      threshold = grid,
      dist = { // Distance from snapping points
         top: Math.abs(snap.top - target.top),
         left: Math.abs(snap.left - target.left),
         bottom: Math.abs(snap.bottom - target.top - h),
         right: Math.abs(snap.right - target.left - w)
      },
      attrs = {
         scaleX: target.scaleX,
         scaleY: target.scaleY,
         top: target.top,
         left: target.left
      };
   switch (target.__corner) {
      case 'tl':
         if (dist.left < dist.top && dist.left < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (w - (snap.left - target.left)) / target.width;
            attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
            attrs.top = target.top + (h - target.height * attrs.scaleY);
            attrs.left = snap.left;
         } else if (dist.top < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (h - (snap.top - target.top)) / target.height;
            attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
            attrs.left = attrs.left + (w - target.width * attrs.scaleX);
            attrs.top = snap.top;
         }
         break;
      case 'mt':
         if (dist.top < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (h - (snap.top - target.top)) / target.height;
            attrs.top = snap.top;
         }
         break;
      case 'tr':
         if (dist.right < dist.top && dist.right < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (snap.right - target.left) / target.width;
            attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
            attrs.top = target.top + (h - target.height * attrs.scaleY);
         } else if (dist.top < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (h - (snap.top - target.top)) / target.height;
            attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
            attrs.top = snap.top;
         }
         break;
      case 'ml':
         if (dist.left < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (w - (snap.left - target.left)) / target.width;
            attrs.left = snap.left;
         }
         break;
      case 'mr':
         if (dist.right < threshold) attrs.scaleX = (snap.right - target.left) / target.width;
         break;
      case 'bl':
         if (dist.left < dist.bottom && dist.left < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (w - (snap.left - target.left)) / target.width;
            attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
            attrs.left = snap.left;
         } else if (dist.bottom < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (snap.bottom - target.top) / target.height;
            attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
            attrs.left = attrs.left + (w - target.width * attrs.scaleX);
         }
         break;
      case 'mb':
         if (dist.bottom < threshold) attrs.scaleY = (snap.bottom - target.top) / target.height;
         break;
      case 'br':
         if (dist.right < dist.bottom && dist.right < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleX = (snap.right - target.left) / target.width;
            attrs.scaleY = (attrs.scaleX / target.scaleX) * target.scaleY;
         } else if (dist.bottom < threshold) {
            attrs.scaleY = (snap.bottom - target.top) / target.height;
            attrs.scaleX = (attrs.scaleY / target.scaleY) * target.scaleX;
         }
         break;
   }
   target.set(attrs);
});
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Working great, but I'd like it to hard snap, like how the moving works. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, the scaling can be a bit odd when you stretch. E.g. the border starts to not match the filling

Comment: um. seems like you could just set `strokeWidth: 0` for the object(s) and that'll fix it

Comment: It doesn't appear to work. target.getWidth is not a function. See this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/sneilan/S9sLu/1873/

Comment: if you stretch the rectangle to be 3 units wide and 2 units tall and then start dragging the diagonal, the snap to grid breaks. The object has to be perfectly square for this to work :(

Answer (score 5):

First of all neither of all answers from above worked with rotated objects and it was a big deal for me. I spent few day on a grid snapping and finally I found a solution that works well, at least it fits my needs. On the first time I did calculations with school math: Math.tan + Pythagorean theorem, but it was too hard and I was pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong.

First of all find and check how `wrapWithFixedAnchor` function works. Basically you can change any attribute of your target: width, height, scaleX, scaleY and then `wrapWithFixedAnchor` will help you to translate your target to the anchor point.

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kod57cwb

I don't think that calling it as a 'snapping' is a good idea, because in reality it would snap to a grid only when objects are zero rotated. Currently it works pretty similar to http://draw.io snapping

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works perfectly. I would add `hasRotatingPoint: false` and `minScaleLimit: 1` to the shapes at a minimum, and possibly `lockScalingFlip: true` and `lockUniScaling: true` as well.

Comment: The stroke also scales with object scaling, so also consider `strokeWidth: 0`.

Answer (score 3):

**This is an update to the accepted answer.**

`target.getWidth()` and `target.getHeight()` don't seem to work anymore, so I updated the fiddle from the accepted answer to replace them with `target.width * target.scaleX` and `target.height * target.scaleY`.

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9sLu/1883/)

Comment: The fiddle is dead.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above don't seem to work anymore.
When the object is resized fabric seems to update the scaleX/scaleY instead of the width/height.

Here is a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ej2hrqm8/

I disabled TL/TR/BL because I cannot get those three corners to work.

```
// Build using FabricJS v3.4

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var snapSize = 20;
var gridSize = 20;

// create grid

for (var i = 0; i < (600 / gridSize); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * gridSize, 0, i * gridSize, 600], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * gridSize, 600, i * gridSize], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }))
}

// add objects

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 50, 
  height: 50, 
  fill: '#faa', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 300, 
  top: 300, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

function Snap(value)
{
  return Math.round(value / snapSize) * snapSize;
}

function SnapMoving(options)
{
  options.target.set({
    left: Snap(options.target.left),
    top: Snap(options.target.top)
  });
}

function SnapScaling(options)
{
  var target = options.target;
  var pointer = options.pointer;

  var px = Snap(pointer.x);
  var py = Snap(pointer.y);
  var rx = (px - target.left) / target.width;
  var by = (py - target.top) / target.height;
  var lx = (target.left - px + (target.width * target.scaleX)) / (target.width);
  var ty = (target.top - py + (target.height * target.scaleY)) / (target.height);

  var a = {};

  // Cannot get snap to work on some corners :-(
  switch (target.__corner)
  {
    case "tl":
      // Not working
      //a = { scaleX: lx, scaleY: ty, left: px, top: py };
      break;
    case "mt":
      a = { scaleY: ty, top: py };
      break;
    case "tr":
      // Not working
      //a = { scaleX: rx, scaleY: ty, top: py  };
      break;
    case "ml":
      a = { scaleX: lx, left: px };
      break;
    case "mr":
      a = { scaleX: rx };
      break;
    case "bl":
      // Not working
      //a = { scaleX: lx, scaleY: by, left: px };
      break;
    case "mb":
      a = { scaleY: by };
      break;
    case "br":
      a = { scaleX: rx, scaleY: by };
      break;
  }

  options.target.set(a);
}

canvas.on({
  "object:moving": SnapMoving,
  "object:scaling": SnapScaling,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `fabric.js` internally computes the size by adding `strokeWidth` to `height` and `width` [see](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line16963). This prevents both the proposed solutions from working properly:

- Etherman's solutions drift when resizing `tl` and `bl` corners.
- GRUNT's one makes the lower right corner wobble while resizing (due to numeric error).

I while share what has worked for me (sorry is in TypeScript)

```js
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

export class GridSnapFabric extends fabric.Canvas {

  protected gridGranularity = 20;

  constructor(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    super(canvas);
    this.on('object:scaling', this.onFabricObjectScaling.bind(this));
  }

  private snapGrid(cord: number): number {
    return Math.round(cord / this.gridGranularity) * this.gridGranularity;
  }

  private onFabricObjectScaling(e: fabric.IEvent) {
    const active = this.getActiveObject();
    const [width, height] = [active.getScaledWidth(), active.getScaledHeight()];

    // X
    if (['tl', 'ml', 'bl'].indexOf(e.transform.corner) !== -1) {
      const tl = this.snapGrid(active.left);
      active.scaleX = (width + active.left - tl) / (active.width + active.strokeWidth);
      active.left = tl;
    } else if (['tr', 'mr', 'br'].indexOf(e.transform.corner) !== -1) {
      const tl = this.snapGrid(active.left + width);
      active.scaleX = (tl - active.left) / (active.width + active.strokeWidth);
    }

    // Y
    if (['tl', 'mt', 'tr'].indexOf(e.transform.corner) !== -1) {
      const tt = this.snapGrid(active.top);
      active.scaleY = (height + active.top - tt) / (active.height + active.strokeWidth);
      active.top = tt;
    } else if (['bl', 'mb', 'br'].indexOf(e.transform.corner) !== -1) {
      const tt = this.snapGrid(active.top + height);
      active.scaleY = (tt - active.top) / (active.height + active.strokeWidth);
    }

    // Avoid singularities
    active.scaleX = (active.scaleY >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.max(Math.abs(active.scaleX), 0.001);
    active.scaleY = (active.scaleY >= 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.max(Math.abs(active.scaleY), 0.001);
  }

}
```

Comment: this is great, thanks. i just removed the protected granularity, so i change it on the fly, but it works nicely.
`const canvas = new GridSnapFabric(document.getElementById("c") as HTMLCanvasElement);
canvas.gridGranularity = GRID_SIZE`
this is how i used it