# Is it possible for fixed scaling in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, scaling

I have rectangle in fabricjs. There are grids in background. Each grid in xAxis is gridSizecolumn and yAxis is gridSizeRow

[image]

How can i scale these rectangle with fixed values, so that it increases according to background grids

> problems faced : un apropriate scaling with below code.
>
> areasCanvas.on('object:scaling', onObjectScaled);

```
function onObjectScaled(e){
    fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
    var obj = e.target;

    avoidCrossingBoundaries(obj)
    console.log(obj)


    obj.set({
        left: Math.round(obj.left / gridSizeColumn) * gridSizeColumn,
        top: Math.round(obj.top / gridSizeRow) * gridSizeRow,
        // height: Math.round(obj.getHeight() / gridSizeRow) * gridSizeRow,
        // width: Math.round(obj.getWidth() / gridSizeColumn) * gridSizeColumn
    });
    obj.setHeight(Math.round(obj.getHeight() / gridSizeRow) * gridSizeRow)
    obj.setWidth(Math.round(obj.getWidth() / gridSizeColumn) * gridSizeColumn)

}
```

Comment: `obj.getHeight() / gridSizeRow) * gridSizeRow` will return exactly the original height. Same for all your calculations with left, top and width. What exactly triggers the scaling here? A change in grid size or what?

Comment: no I am getting fixed height. getHeight() gives exact height on scaling. scaling triggers resize of rectabgle above grids

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the rects' `width` and `height`, you also need to reset their `scaleX`/`scaleY` on each `scale` event:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c")

const img = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 20,
  top: 20,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red'
})
canvas.add(img)

function onObjectScaled(e){
    const gridSizeColumn = 20
    const gridSizeRow = 20
    fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;
    var obj = e.target;

    // avoidCrossingBoundaries(obj)
    // console.log(obj)


    obj.set({
        left: Math.round(obj.left / gridSizeColumn) * gridSizeColumn,
        top: Math.round(obj.top / gridSizeRow) * gridSizeRow,
        // height: Math.round(obj.getHeight() / gridSizeRow) * gridSizeRow,
        // width: Math.round(obj.getWidth() / gridSizeColumn) * gridSizeColumn
    });

    obj.set({
      // set new width and height
      width: Math.round(obj.getHeight() / gridSizeRow) * gridSizeRow,
      height: Math.round(obj.getWidth() / gridSizeColumn) * gridSizeColumn, 
      // reset scaleX and scaleY
      scaleX: 1,
      scaleY: 1
    })
}

canvas.on('object:scaling', onObjectScaled);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

Note: you didn't specify the fabric.js version so I assumed you're using v1.x.x (v2 doesn't have `.getHeight()`/`.getWidth()` anymore)

Comment: yes I am using 1.7.2 version. scaleX and ScaleY somehow fixed.But i think its not optimum for my problem. still scaling is increasing with respect to background grids

Comment: @RajeshChoudary wait, isn't that what you wanted? *"How can i scale these rectangle with fixed values, so that it increases according to background grids"*

Comment: But by doing scaleX = 1 its not incresing according to background grids

Comment: @RajeshChoudary did you try running the snippet? Yes, the scaleX/scaleY stay the same, the width/height are increased instead

Comment: hey I found solution. there is lot more things to do fit the background grids.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147762/fabricjs-snap-to-grid-on-resize

Comment: @RajeshChoudary sure, feel free to use whatever solution fits you. But I still struggle to understand what part of the above snippet didn't meet your expectations, given the description in your question.

Comment: @RajeshChoudary also, the solution you found doesn't work for 3x2 rectangles, just FYI